# Filter on date relative to today but the dates are in separate fields

Tags: sql, date, filter

I have a table where the date parts are in separate fields and I am struggling to put a filter on it (pulling all the data is so much that it basically times out).

How can I write a sql query to pull the data for only the past 7 days?

```
| eventinfo  | entity                  | year | month | day |
|------------|-------------------------|------|-------|-----|
| source=abc | abc=030,abd=203219,.... | 2022 | 08    | 07  |
| source=abc | abc=030,abd=203219,.... | 2022 | 08    | 05  |
| source=abc | abc=030,abd=203219,.... | 2022 | 07    | 33  |
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use concatenation on your columns, convert them to date and then apply the filter.

```
-- Oracle database
select *
from event
where to_date( year||'-'||month||'-'||day,'YYYY-MM-DD') >= trunc(sysdate) - 7;
```

Comment: Thanks with above and some other topics from here I managed to get it to work with `where cast( "year"||'-'||"month"||'-'||."day" As Date) >= current_date - interval '5' day``